# Time picker not returning value in flutter app

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker

I am using   flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.1 to be able to pick dates and time for scheduled events.

Here is the screen I am using:

[image]

The Start Time field is where I am having problems. When I click in the field the Time Picker is displayed. Once I select a time and click "Ok" the text field does not get the selected time.

Here is the code I have inside the onTap: property:

```
onTap: () async {
                    TimeOfDay _timePicked = await (showTimePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialTime: new TimeOfDay.now()) as FutureOr<TimeOfDay>);
                    if (_timePicked != null) {
                      _dt = DateTime(_selectedDate!.year, _selectedDate!.month, _selectedDate!.day, _timePicked.hour, _timePicked.minute);
                      setState(() {
                        eventStartTimeController.text = DateFormat('h:mm a').format(_dt); //_timePicked.format(context);
                        eventProvider.changeeventstarttime(_dt);
                      });
                    }
                  },
```

When debugging, the execution does not stop at any break point set after I have selected a time.  What is going on here?

I have upgraded to Dart 2, null-safety so I don't know if this has anything to do with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is here

**... as FutureOr);**

Try this one, it works fine

```
final TimeOfDay _timePicked = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
);
 if (_timePicked != null) {
  _dt = DateTime(
  _selectedDate.year,
  _selectedDate.month,
  _selectedDate.day,
  _timePicked.hour,
  _timePicked.minute,
 );
 setState(() {
  eventStartTimeController.text = DateFormat('h:mm a')
   .format(_dt); //_timePicked.format(context);
  eventProvider.changeeventstarttime(_dt);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to this. it will work.

```
TimeOfDay _timePicked = await (showTimePicker(
                    context: context,
                    initialTime: new TimeOfDay.now()) as FutureOr<TimeOfDay>);
                if (_timePicked != null) {
                  _dt = DateTime(_selectedDate!.year, _selectedDate!.month, _selectedDate!.day, _timePicked.hour, _timePicked.minute);
                  setState(() {
                     final localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
                     final formattedTimeOfDay = localizations.formatTimeOfDay(_timePicked!,alwaysUse24HourFormat: false);
                    eventStartTimeController.text = formattedTimeOfDay;  
                    eventProvider.changeeventstarttime(_dt);
                  });
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I am still not getting a time in the "Start Time" textfield. I will edit my original post so you can see my code. Maybe I did something wrong.